# How to write / build testing case in Android Studio 0.2.x

Tags: android, testing, android-studio

I use Android Studio ( 0.2.1 ) to develop Android APP, and follow the user guide ( http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing ) to configure testing.
But when I run command "gradle connectedInstrumentTest" to test my testing case, I always got the “BUILD SUCCESSFUL” result.

Following is my configuration and testing case :

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testPackageName "com.demo.mobile.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
}
```

**src/instrumentTest/java/com/demo/mobile/test**

```
package com.demo.mobile.test;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.demo.mobile.MainActivity;
import junit.framework.Assert;

public class OrmLiteTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    private TextView mView;

    public OrmLiteTest(Class<MainActivity> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass);
    }

    public void testGetHelper() {
        Assert.assertTrue(2 + 2 == 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mainActivity = this.getActivity();
    }
}
```

Anyone an idea how this can be solved, or I do the something wrong in Android Studio.
Thanks.

Comment: What are you expecting to get back, if not "BUILD SUCCESSFUL"?

Comment: can you post the output of ./gradlew tasks prints ?

Comment: I can't run activity test, they simply are not invoked at all. Normal tests (based on normal TestCase) run fine though. I don't know why instrumentation tests are not run.

Comment: @Thoma.Yu Demo for testcase in android using intrumentationTestcase http://goo.gl/9F9SI7

Comment: @Thomas.Yu Demo for how to run testcase  http://goo.gl/ac06C0 and example to run network call test http://goo.gl/bQFlmU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your code.

The constructor in your `OrmLiteTest` is written to take a Class. This may not be so. What you need is:

```
public OrmLiteTest() {
    super(MainActivity.class);
}
```

Notice how the constructor doesn't have any parameters.

An issue is that the constructor which Android Studio generates includes the   Class parameter.